# Why is my JFrame not appearing in a web based Java app?

Tags: java, swing, applet, jframe

I have a game application that I will be running in a web browser using the  tag.
This program has a JFrame, which displays a couple of tabs allowing navigation throughout the program.
When I run the program locally it will work fine, displaying the JFrame and working in entirety.
However when I upload it to the host and visit it's link the JFrame will not display..

I have searched about 3 hours and simply must not be able to provide the correct keywords for my siutation.
All I can get in results is the JFrame not appearing at all, locally or web app.

This is how the client looks when I run it locally from the same .jar:

[image: Picture - Local]

This is how the client looks in a web browser (tried IE, FF and Chrome):

[image: Picture - Web]

Applet.java:

```
public class Client extends RSApplet {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            instance = new Client();
            new UserInterface(args);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

GUI.java

```
public class GUI extends Applet implements ActionListener, WindowListener, FocusListener {

    public UserInterface(String args[]) {
        try {
        /* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */
        /* Metal                                                                    */
        /*  UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");    */
        /* System Look                                                              */
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        /* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */
            initGUI();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void initGUI() {
        try {
            JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
            JPopupMenu.setDefaultLightWeightPopupEnabled(false);
            frame = new JFrame(frameTitle);
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            Image icon = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(iconDir);
            frame.setIconImage(icon);
            gamePanel = new JPanel();
            gamePanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            gamePanel.add(this);
            gamePanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(850, 600));
            frame.getContentPane().add(gamePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                    if (loggedIn == false) {
                        System.exit(0);
                    } else {
                        if (showMessage("Are you sure you want to close the game?") == true) {
                            System.exit(0);
                        } else return;
                    }
                }
            });
            initMenuBar();
            frame.pack();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setResizable(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void initMenuBar() {
        menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        /** File **/
        fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
        String[] fileMenuItems = {
            "Quit"
        };
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);
        /** Quick Links **/
        linksMenu = new JMenu("Quick Links");
        String[] linksMenuItems = {
            "Home", "News", "Donate"
        };
        menuBar.add(linksMenu);
        frame.getContentPane().add(menuBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to put the application on a web page, i mean to run as a web application. If yes then you want an Applet or JApplet and not a frame. A frame works normally but for you to add it to a website then you need to make it an applet. Make use of the links below..

JApplet class for se6- http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JApplet.html
JApplet/Applet tutorial -- http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html

Good Luck

Comment: Alright, I'll read up on them right fast, thanks for the reply. Will this require me to have two different copies of code as I want to allow users to download the .jar to their computer to run outside of the web browser should they choose to. Or will this allow the bar to be drawn on both the web app and when ran locally?

Comment: There is something called web start(jnlp) I have just written 2 apps in that form so I really dont know much but if its not a very big application then you can make 2 different ones. One is jar while the other is an applet.

Comment: I just looked at your code and can see you have started using Applet but you do not have the required methods like init(), start(), and stop(). At least the init() method has to be overidden

Comment: Alright, well at your first comment back, it is not a small application, running about 356kb, it isn't large, but it isn't small. I can provide two applications if necessary. @2nd comment: Yeah I see what you mean, reading the tut on how to make one now. =P