# Java Web Development Beginner

Tags: java, web, applet

I've been doing a lot with java lately, And I'd like to start doing some web development with it.. The kind of applet I'd like to make, Is the sort where it's a frame that loads up with Java's logo, and then runs the application inside. Sorta like what you would find here: http://minecraft.net/play - It's just a window that the java application runs in. I'd like to know if someone can help me get started.. I already know some Java, Like I said. And I've been using netbeans to try to figure this all out.. But so far, I can't figure out how to get that type of a window to display.. I can get basic html output, but I would like for example, to run myClass.class in a frame inside the web page..

myClass.class might have code like this:

```
public class myClass {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        public String s = "I am foobar.";
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

And I would want the output to be that Java frame, with the simple output "I am foobar" inside..

Thanks again for any help getting me started..

Comment: Don't use client side Java for textual web page output.

Comment: That's not what I was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're looking for applets.

Get started here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Just create a java frame and add contents to it.

Just to get started,

http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-JFrame.html

Comment: How do i get the class to display on the web page though.. I already know how to use jFrames in normal java..

Comment: You need an applet if u want to run it as a web application http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6010925/why-is-my-jframe-not-appearing-in-a-web-based-java-app Would this help?